# Why href doesn't fire?

Tags: jquery, html, css, href

Why href of this anchor doesn't fire ?

http://jsfiddle.net/3ho7ommm/4/

```
<span class="menuoptions active">
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: that's a span tag shown ...it has no `href`. Please post code within the question itself. We shouldn't have to go offsite to understand your issue. Also explain your issues in more detail

Comment: The click events are firing for me (on Chrome 41). However, you are closing that span tag with a div tag. Maybe try fixing that first. I would change the span to a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is firing up but u are not able to see it in fiddle result window.

More over you are passing #

```
<a href="#" id="notificationLink">
```

which keeps the link on same page 
and in code

```
$("#notificationLink").click(function()
    {
        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
        $("#notificationContainer2").fadeOut(300);
        return false;
    });
```

return false statement is stooping the href tag to perform its normal functionality

Comment: No i'd like to know why HREF inside of notificationContainer doesn't fire.

Comment: //Popup Click
  $("#notificationContainer").click(function()
 {
  return false
 }); this return false is stoping the href to do its normal functionality, comment it and see code will work